# Serializing/Deserializing model using spray json scala test

Tags: scala, scalatest, spray-json

I am new to scala and writing test cases using scala test and spray json. My code is as follows.

```
case class MyModel(Point1: String,
                          Point2: String,
                          Point3: Seq[String],
                          Point4: Seq[String])

  it should "serialise/deserialize a MyModel to JSON" in {
    val json= """{"Point1":"","Point3":[],"Point2":"","Point4":[]}""".parseJson
    val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]

    myModelViaJson.Point1 shouldBe ""
    myModelViaJson.Point3.isEmpty shouldBe true
    myModelViaJson.Point2 shouldBe ""
    myModelViaJson.Point4.isEmpty shouldBe true
  }
```

On doing sbt test I am geting following error

```
 should serialise/deserialize a MyModel to JSON *** FAILED ***
[info]   spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected String as JsString, but got []
[info]   at spray.json.package$.deserializationError(package.scala:23)
[info]   at spray.json.ProductFormats.fromField(ProductFormats.scala:63)
[info]   at spray.json.ProductFormats.fromField$(ProductFormats.scala:51)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]` before parsing.

Refer: [jsonformats-for-case-classes](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes)

So, the code will look like

```scala
val json= """{"Point1":"","Point3":[],"Point2":"","Point4":[]}""".parseJson
implicit val format = jsonFormat4(MyModel)
val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]

myModelViaJson.Point1 shouldBe ""
myModelViaJson.Point3.isEmpty shouldBe true
myModelViaJson.Point2 shouldBe ""
myModelViaJson.Point4.isEmpty shouldBe true
```

Comment: Hi, could you please answer my this question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242326/scala-test-issues/66243113#66243113 that will be so helpful