# Scala test issues

Tags: scala, scalatest, spray-json

I am new to Scala and writing test cases using Scala test and spray json. My code is as follows:

```
case class MyModel(Point1: String,
                          Point2: String,
                          Point3: Option[NewModel] = None)


case class NewModel(Point4: Boolean,
                          Point5: Boolean,
                          Point6: Boolean)

it should "serialise/deserialize a MyModel to JSON" in {
    val json= """{"Point1":"","Point3":[],"Point2":""}""".parseJson
    val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]

    myModelViaJson.Point1 shouldBe ""
    myModelViaJson.Point3.head.point4 shouldBe true
    myModelViaJson.Point2 shouldBe ""
}
```

I am getting following error on running test case

```
should serialise/deserialize a MyModel to JSON *** FAILED ***
[info]   spray.json.DeserializationException: Object expected in field 'point4'
[info]   at spray.json.package$.deserializationError(package.scala:23)
[info]   at spray.json.ProductFormats.fromField(ProductFormats.scala:63)
[info]   at spray.json.ProductFormats.fromField$(ProductFormats.scala:51)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: RAZZZ, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON sets the value of `Point3` to `[]` which is an empty array, but in the Scala it should be a `NewModel` object (hence "Object expected").

The use of `Option` in `MyModel` says that the field might be missing from the JSON, in which case the extracted value will be `None`. If the `Point3` field is present in the JSON, it should contain the JSON for a `NewModel`, and the field will then be `Some(<NewModel instance>)`.

Comment: Didn't understood much. Could you please give example by putting values in my problem

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate the correct answer by @Tim. There is incompatibility between the provided Json, and the model. The json has `Point3` as an array, while in `MyModel` it is `Option[NewModel]`. Therefore, the first cannot be deserialised into the latter. There are many ways to solve it, which depends on what you want.

1. The easiest, remove `Point3` from the Json:

   ```
   val json= """{"Point1":"","Point2":""}""".parseJson
   val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]
   ```

   It will produce `MyModel(,,None)`
2. Change the Json to have `NewModel`:

   ```
   val json= """{"Point1":"","Point3":{ "Point4": true, "Point5": true, "Point6": true },"Point2":""}""".parseJson
   val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]
   ```

   Which produces `MyModel(,,Some(NewModel(true,true,true)))`
3. In case you really meant to have array there, you can change the `MyModel` class:

   ```
   case class MyModel(Point1: String,
                      Point2: String,
                      Point3: Option[Seq[NewModel]] = None)
   ```

   Then the following:

   ```
   val json= """{"Point1":"","Point3":[],"Point2":""}""".parseJson
   val myModelViaJson= json.convertTo[MyModel]
   ```

   produces: `MyModel(,,Some(List()))`